# Piece of code that compiles with gcc but not g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is this a legitimate C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372062/is-this-a-legitimate-c-code)
>   [“C subset of C++” -> Where not ? examples ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/c-subset-of-c-where-not-examples)

Could anybody come up with a piece of code that compiles with gcc or any other C compiler, and doesn't compile g++ or any other C++ compiler?

UPDATE:
I don't mean just keywords

UPDATE2:
Thank you All for answers. Apparently moderators were less enthusiastic than I was about subtle differences between C and C++.

UPDATE3:
to moderators: could you merge it with my previous question on the topic, as you suggested? It makes perfect sense to keep these two question together.

Comment: No, do your own homework

Comment: maybe it looks like, but it's not. It's a natural continuation of a question I've just asked

Comment: You were given examples in the comment thread where you asked.

Comment: I swear they were not there when I asked this question

Comment: @matcheek: fair enough, I think pts did edit the comment at least once.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* s = malloc(128);
    return 0;
}
```

This will compile with gcc, but not with g++.  C++ requires an explicit cast from `void*` here, whereas C does not.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main(int argc, char **class)
{
    return !argc;
}
```

---

Edit: another example

```
int foo();
int main(void) {
    return foo(42);
}
int foo(int bar) {
    return bar - 42;
}
```

Comment: OK the keyword class, but if we forget keywords about the keywords?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
extern int getSize();

int main()
{
    char x[getSize()];
    x[0] = 0;
}

int getSize()
{
     return 4;
}
```

Remember to compile with the strict flags.

```
> gcc -pedantic -std=c99 t.c
> g++ -pedantic t.c
t.c: In function `int main()':
t.c:6: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array `x'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
/* Within a function */
{
  enum {foo} bar;
  bar++;
}
```

That seems a pretty big breaking change in the design of C++, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

What about character size:
Even worse is that it compiles but produces different output at runtime.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", (sizeof('\xFF') == sizeof(char))?"OK":"Fail");
}

> gcc -pedantic t.c
> ./a.exe
Fail
> g++ -pedantic t.c
> ./a.exe
OK
```

This actually makes we wonder why this works?

```
fprintf(stdout, "%c%c\n", 'A', 'B');
```

It works on both compilers even though the size of the objects are different.

Comment: works because all "small" integer types are promoted to `int` in any case when passed to a varag function.

Answer (score 1):

pointer arithmetics on `void*`:

```
void* t;
t++; // compiles only in gcc
```